# Sending an embed through an interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send an embed after using an interaction command but the following error occurs:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
          
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

```js
if (interaction.commandName == "ping") {
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setTitle("Pong")
        .setDescription("Some description here");
    interaction.reply(exampleEmbed);
}
```

I have read that I need to send it as an array, but how do I do this here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick read through [Sending messages, embeds, files, etc.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc), you have to do it like this:

```js
if (interaction.commandName == "ping") {
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setTitle("Pong")
        .setDescription("Some description here");
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
```